# How to know the version of the local scalatra install?

Tags: scalatra

I am using scalatra on ubuntu 13.

However I am not sure if it is still the most up to date version.

How to know the version of the local scalatra install?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your build.scala file, you should find the following variable:

```
val ScalatraVersion = "2.2.2" //The version is 2.2.2 in this example
```

If not, then look at the libraryDependencies variable, which should contain the version of Scalatra you are running:

```
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion
```